# Ruby - Finding the third greatest value in an array - need help understanding method.

Tags: ruby

new to coding! I love it and have been doing a lot of practice problems to help me qualify for a program I am looking to apply to next year. This is probably a very simple question for many of you, thanks in advance for the help.

One of the problems listed was to find the third greatest value in an array of numbers. This is very easy.

However, the coding problems I am doing come with a solution and it's usually a solution that doesn't use a lot of built in methods so it's harder for me to understand.

```
    #my solution
    def third_greatest(num)
      array = num.sort.reverse
      return array[2]
    end
```

What I would like to know is how the while loop works in their solution. I can't seem to understand what is going on.

```
    #their solution
    def third_greatest(nums)
      first = nil
      second = nil
      third = nil

      idx = 0
      while idx < nums.length
        value = nums[idx]
        if first == nil || value > first
          third = second
          second = first
          first = value
        elsif second == nil || value > second
          third = second
          second = value
        elsif third == nil || value > third
          third = value
        end

        idx += 1
      end

      return third
    end
```

Comment: The verbose solution keeps track of the top highest 3 values with each iteration. On each iteration, it reshuffles the top 3 based upon what the next value in the array it sees. You should manually run through a simple example, and you'll see how it works.

Comment: Both solutions are possibly flawed. Also consider what happens when you have duplicate values in the array, unless stated that inputs will contain no duplicates.

Comment: Tracing through a program by hand is an essential skill.  Get out a pad of paper and pencil (or use a whiteboard or chalkboard) and work through a small problem - go line-by-line and record or update the values of the variables as per the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided solution keeps track of the `first`, `second`, and `third` largest values in the array. These all start out as `nil`. The `while` loop goes through each element in the array one at a time, and compares that element to the current largest 3 values (that is, the largest 3 values that have been seen thus far, as we work our way through the array). If any of those "top 3" values are still `nil`, or if the current element being examined is larger than any of those values, then the current value is inserted into the correct place in the "top 3" (by assigning it to either `first`, `second`, or `third`, but only after first "shifting over" the preexisting values contained in those "top 3" variables).

For example, if `first` is currently `7`, `second` is `4`, and `third` is `3`, and the current element that I'm checking is `10`, then I want to shift `4` (i.e. `second`) into `third` place, then shift `7` (i.e. `first`) into `second` place, and then assign `10` to be the new `first`.

---

Your solution has the advantage of being simpler to read (and to write). You might be wondering if there is any advantage gained by the relative complexity of the provided solution. There is. I don't know if you have learned about time complexity / Big O notation, yet, but the provided solution is `O(n)` (because it basically just makes a single loop through the array), which will have better performance on average compared to your solution, which is `O(n log(n))` (the best/lowest possible time complexity for any algorithm that involves sorting an array).